# jquery to access node js session variable from Jquery

Tags: jquery, node.js

How can I display session value which is stored in Node js from Jquery.
I am using **express** module on the node-js side. 
My code looks like the following.

```
    var express = require('express');
    var app = express();

    app.use(express.cookieParser());
    app.use(express.session({secret: '************'}));

    app.get('/radical', function(req, res) {
        req.session.lastPage = '/radical';
        res.send('What a radical visit!');
    });
```

I want the **lastPage** to be displayed on the html through JQuery.

Answer (score 0):

You could just pass the current value of `req.session.lastPage` to the page when it loads. So on a page where you need to know the last page:

```
res.render('thePage',{lastPage:req.session.lastPage});
```

Then client side

```
var lastPage = "<%=lastPage%>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to *render* your value to a *template*.

The Express docs include a section on [Using template engines with Express](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html)

In your case, this might look something like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'pug');

app.get('/radical', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index', {lastPage: 'radical'});
});
```